# VS2008 Help: How can I limit the index & search to just topics I want?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, documentation

Time was that I could **F1** a symbol in my .cpp or .h file, and I'd be given a reasonable list of possible topics to delve into.

That was long, long ago.

These days, I press F1 and I'm rarely given information that is even vaguely, tangentially or tenuously related to the API or subsystem in question.  Instead, I am deluged with Windows Mobile APIs, .NET gibberish, VB crud, ASP rigmarole, unrelated COM interfaces, etc.

I work with three libraries predominately:

- Win32 API
- C++ standard library (and the still supported C libraries)
- MFC

Does anyone know how to get the sadly unfocused help system in VS2008 to retrieve only those topics of actual relevance to the type of programming one is doing, as opposed to a search against every possible symbol of a similar name in every technology Microsoft has ever done?

Alternately - can you suggest better places to lookup details for MFC, Win32 API, and C++ programming in general?  I'm a seasoned programmer, but I cannot remember every nuance and detail of every API, and I have this bizarre desire to let the computer do that remembering for me... if only I can figure out how to make it be genuinely helpful...

Comment: I think MSDN covers MFC pretty well, I know it has great documentation for Win32, and just googling can give you most answers to C++ question, I think. Or here. :) That said, you can disable what comes up by category somewhere on the help screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [H2reg](http://helpware.net/mshelp2/h2reg.ini.htm) to register/unregister help files in your default visual studio namespace.

Comment: Does anyone have an example as to how to apply that tool to this situation?